# Regex for validating postcode and phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a form, with warning elements. All works great but need to define my patterns better.

```
                $("#postcode").inputNotes( 
              {
                warning: {
                  pattern: /^[0-9]+$/,
                  type: 'note',
                  text: 'Only numbers, please ...',
                  inversedBehavior: true
                }
              }
            );
            $("#phone").inputNotes( 
              {
                warning: {
                  pattern: /^[0-9]+$/,
                  type: 'note',
                  text: 'Only numbers, no spaces please ...',
                  inversedBehavior: true
                }
              }
            );
```

Ok for the Postcode warning, I want the pattern to expect 4 numbers

For the Phone warning, I want the pattern to expect 10 numbers.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

For 6 digit or 10 digit numbers:
 `pattern: /^[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{6}$/,`

For four digit Postcode: `pattern: /^[0-9]{4}$/,`

For 10 digit Phone number:
(if phone number can't start with 0)
 `pattern: /^[1-9][0-9]{9}$/,`

(if phone number can start with 0)
 `pattern: /^[0-9]{10}$/,`

Comment: Why can't the phone number start with a `0`?

Comment: Thanks so much, sorted Brilliant

Comment: @alex: Have not seen any 10 digit phone number starting with a 0. Updated the post with a note just in case the numbers do exist.

Comment: Mobile numbers start with 0 and we require user to type in their state prefix ( australia ) which starts 01 , 02 etc

Comment: @Cybernate Where I and @422 are from (Australia), mobile numbers start with a `0` (unless using their country code prefix, e.g. `+61`).

Comment: Thanks Alex, yep.. we also have ip address page validation, so this particular page only displays for australian IP's. You guys are bloody great

Comment: OOps also meant to mention, all numbers in Oz are 10 numbers long, unless they are 13 numbers

Comment: In fact .. would be cool, to adapt the regex to allow 6 digit 13 numbers ( example ) 131415

Comment: @422: Updated the post, pls check

Comment: @422 Keep in mind I can proxy to your site (different IP) and you may think I'm in Australian when I'm really not.

Comment: @ cybernate thats great, issue is.. if user types more than 6 but less than 10 the text alert disappears. As it is we display the message onload, and upon regex pattern match the message disappears. This works at 6 digits entered, and vanishes, and stays vanished even if we add 7 digits.. which kind of negates the issue. Perhaps we should add this across 2 alternate form fields to cope with 6 digit or 10 digit numbers.

Comment: @alex. Yep totally aware of the proxy, we kind of combat that by storing members ip within the dB , the form only being accesible to members logged in. Its as much as we can do. Otherwise form does not display to non logged in users, but understand they can bypass this via proxy.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the rules for Australian postcodes:

ACT: 0200-0299 and 2600-2639.

NSW: 1000-1999, 2000-2599 and 2640-2914.

NT: 0900-0999 and 0800-0899.

QLD: 9000-9999 and 4000-4999.

SA: 5000-5999.

TAS: 7800-7999 and 7000-7499.

VIC: 8000-8999 and 3000-3999.

WA: 6800-6999 and 6000-6799

**Regular Expression: ^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$**

Pass: 0200|||7312|||2415

Fail: 0300|||7612|||2915

Comment: Updated regex for current postcode ranges (as of 2019): `^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([123456789][0-9]{3})$`

Answer (score 11):

Australia Post has greatly simplified the rules in 2019.
You now only need to account for the ranges:
**0200 – 0299, 0800-0999 and 1000 – 9999**

So the Regular Expression for Validating Australian Postcodes is just:

```
^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]{3})$
```

Comment: This will match `123456`, because the `^` and `$` are assigned to the 1st and 2nd alternatives respectively (so the `3456` matches `([1-9][0-9]{3})$`). However modifying it slightly to: `^(0[289][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3})$` (so a single capturing group) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For a 4 digit postcode, you can use `/^\d{4}$/`.

For a 10 digit postcode, you can use `/^\d{10}$/`.

Keep in mind some people will type spaces, parenthesis etc into the phone number. You should strip all non digits first before validating with `/[^\d]+/g`.

Comment: Thnaks, so what is the difference between your regex and @cybernate ? now I am really confused

Comment: @422 Not a great deal really, I just used the `\d` shorthand for the `[0-9]` character class and mine allows a leading `0`.

Comment: Gottya, will use that on other regex, great point. first time I have played with this...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `+` modifier, try using `{num}`, where `num` is the number of instances of the previous atom you want.

Comment: Cheers have added that to my side notes as a pointer appreciate answer :)

Answer (score 1):

All these answers are assuming that you limit the text field to 4 characters eg. (12345) is valid, to limit the length use the following

```
^(0[289][0-9]{2})$|^([1-9][0-9]{3})$
```

Answer (score 0):

just to save people time here is an example of how to use in jquery

```
 $("#address-postal-code").once().on('blur', function (e) {
    var myRegEx = new RegExp('^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]{3})$');
    var ele = $(this);
    if (!myRegEx.test(ele.val())) {
        console.log('no good');
    }
    else {
        console.log('good');
    }
})
```